# how to convert a string representing an encoded char (eg "0x79" or "\n" ) to its represented integer value without lookup tables

Tags: c

The title says it all, really.   I want to pass a string to a function and have that function return with the appropriate integer.

ie:

```
int function(char *encodedString) {
    something here;
}
```

eg:

```
i = function("0x79");
print("printed output  %x", i);
```

printed output   79

Comment: What is the expected output for `function("\n")`?

Answer (score 1):

Use the C standard function, [`strtol`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/)
Its out-parameter (2nd param) will tell you if you should accept its result, or de-reference the string directly for values like `"\n"` and `"\t"`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int function(char *encodedString) {
    char* next;
    int answer = strtol(encodedString, &next, 0);
    answer = (next-encodedString)? answer : *encodedString;
    return answer;
}

int main(void) {
    int i = function("0x79");
    printf("printed output  0x%02X\n", i);
    
    i = function("\n");
    printf("printed output  0x%02X\n", i); 
    
    return 0;
}
```

[Code at IDEOne](https://ideone.com/lRGlDZ)

#### Output:

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 4364KB
printed output  0x79
printed output  0x0A
```